# Is there another way to show / hide fields based on html5 data attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a bootstrap modal to add some content to products. There's a button to open a modal, which sends some of the products info thru html5 data-attributes (data-product="product name", data-product-id="99", etc).

How to open different modals based on the button you are clicking on? It should get product NUMBER and NAME and, based on the button (add, move, remove), open different fields on modal.

HTML TABLE

```
<tr id="1">
  <td>Product A NUMBER</td>
  <td>Product A NAME</td>
  <td><a data-id="add" type="button" data-target="#Inventory" data-toggle="modal">Add</a></td>
  <td><a data-id="move" type="button" data-target="#Inventory" data-toggle="modal">Move</a></td>
  <td><a data-id="add" type="button" data-target="#Inventory" data-toggle="modal">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
  <td>Product B NUMBER</td>
  <td>Product B NAME</td>
  <td><a data-id="add" type="button" data-target="#Inventory" data-toggle="modal">Add</a></td>
  <td><a data-id="move" type="button" data-target="#Inventory" data-toggle="modal">Move</a></td>
  <td><a data-id="add" type="button" data-target="#Inventory" data-toggle="modal">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

MODAL DIV

```
<div id="Inventory" class="modal">
  <...>
    <div id="FIELD-TO-SHOW-TO-ADD-BUTTON">
      <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">ADD</label>
      <input type="text" name="add">
    </div>             
    <div id="FIELD-TO-SHOW-TO-MOVE-BUTTON">
      <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">MOVE</label>
      <input type="text" name="move">
    </div>   
    <div id="FIELD-TO-SHOW-TO-REMOVE-BUTTON">
      <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">MOVE</label>
      <input type="text" name="move">
    </div>   
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#Inventory').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
if (action === "add") {
        $("div[id=add-inventory]").show();
        $("div[id=move-inventory]").hide();
        $("div[id=remove-inventory]").hide();
      } else if (action == "move") {
        $("div[id=add-inventory]").hide();
        $("div[id=move-inventory]").show();
        $("div[id=remove-inventory]").hide();
      } else if (action == "remove") {
        $("div[id=add-inventory]").hide();
        $("div[id=move-inventory]").hide();
        $("div[id=remove-inventory]").show();
};
```

But I don't know how JS can catch the product's data-id or if there's an better way to do that. Thanks in advance! I'm sorry, this is my very first post, although I use stackoverflow for a long time! :)

EDIT:
I think I didn't explained properly. What I need:

BUTTON A [data-tag="X", data-tag2="Y", data-tag3="Z"]
BUTTON B [data-tag="X", data-tag2="Y", data-tag3="Z"]

It doesn't matter what button I hit, it's gonna open a MODAL with a form, but I need to keep those datas from the button pressed, to be inserted as a  field, so I can get all the infos from the BUTTON pressed + all the infos from the form that opens on modal.

**EDIT 2 [SOLVED]:**

I had 3 buttons for each product shown. One for ADD, one for MOVE and another one for REMOVE. After button clicked, a modal pops up with a form. As soon as you submit it, the JS responsible for opening the modal should get the data from this form, but it wasn't getting, until I found the solution to add something like this:

```
if (action === "add") {
  product_amount = modal.find('#amount1').val();
} else if (action == "move") {
  product_amount = modal.find('#amount2').val();
  userToMove = modal.find('#userToMove').val();
} else if (action == "remove") {
  product_amount = modal.find('#amount3').val();
}
```

Where each #amount ID refers to the button pressed to open the modal.

Thanks a lot for everyone who helped and I'm sorry I wasn't able to explain the issue properly due to my limitations with the language [english]. Thanks! :)

Comment: `div[id=add-inventory]` <= why are you doing attribute selectors for exact id matching?  This circumvents the performance gains the browser offers by making id look ups super fast.

Comment: Though related to your actual question: [Bootstrap Modal Varying Modal Content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) explains how to do this.

Comment: @Taplar, I did my code based on that page. But it doesn't carry other variables from the button used to start the modal. And that's what my question is about. :) Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have no idea on how to do it with a different manner. It's kinda workaround  for a dumb programmer like me :)

Comment: id selectors are `#add-inventory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you need but I needed to explain more than just a comment:

to show/hide based on data attribute:

```
$('div[data-product="product name"]').show();
$('div[data-product="product name"]').hide();
```

to get the data attribute of the div:

```
$(".someClass").data('product');
```

to get any attribute you like:

```
$(".someClass").attr('something-product');
```

**UPDATE** on your comment:

```
var tag = $(".someClass").data("tag1"); //data-tag1 value of the button
$('input').attr("data-tag1",tag); //set input's data-tag1 to buttons data-tag1
```

make sure you specify which input you want it to be assigned to. just to make sure so it doesn't assign to any other unwanted inputs

Comment: Thanks for your code. I think I didn't explained properly. What I need:

BUTTON A [data-tag="X", data-tag2="Y", data-tag3="Z"]
BUTTON B [data-tag="X", data-tag2="Y", data-tag3="Z"]

It doesn't matter what button I hit, it's gonna open a MODAL with a form, but I need to keep those datas from the buttons, to be inserted as a <input type="hidden">, so I can get all the infos from the BUTTON pressed + all the infos from the from that opens on modal.

Comment: @teco I updated the answer hope that helps you can modify that based on your needs. first you get the data-tag1 value then assign it to whatever input you want

Comment: I just tried to read my message again and I really didn't understood the way I explained. It got really confused. Thanks for your attention and code. I had done this step before I got stuck into the question. Finally I found a solution: I was able to open modal, but the JS was not getting the proper data from the button pressed. So I had to create an statement that IF button A was pressed, then get the values of the specific form. I'm gonna update the code, if someone has this question in the future. Once again, thanks!